# MYSQL Select specific amount of duplicate values in column sorted by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT notes.* FROM notes 
WHERE notes.id IN (
SELECT T1.id 
FROM notes as T1 
WHERE ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM notes as T2 
    WHERE T2.category_id = T1.category_id 
    AND T2.created_at > T1.created_at 
    AND T1.user_id = T2.user_id
) < N
) 
AND user_id = 2
```

This query selects N rows in each category_id sorted by created_at.
Everything works perfectly until:

1) Number of results is > 50 because the performance drop is linear or worse: 2.6 seconds for 200 rows even with indexes.

2) Several equal created_at values is presented in results. You will get more than N rows in category in that case.

The main question is how to optimize this query or may be write another one with the same functionality? Required performance is 0.5 seconds for 1000 rows for specific user_id.
Point 2 is optional. Performance is the main issue.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa713f/3

EXPLAIN:

```
1   PRIMARY notes   
NULL
ref PRIMARY,user_id user_id 4   const   654 100.00  
NULL

1   PRIMARY T1  
NULL
eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   admin_bt.notes.id   1   100.00  Using where 
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  T2  
NULL
ref category_id,created_at,user_id,catcrbabusr  catcrbabusr 4   admin_bt.T1.category_id 1148    3.33    Using where; Using index
```

Comment: Can you provide the EXPLAIN for same

Comment: 1 PRIMARY notes 
    NULL
 ref PRIMARY,user_id user_id 4 const 654 100.00 
    NULL
 
1 PRIMARY T1 
    NULL
 eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 admin_bt.notes.id 1 100.00 Using where 
3 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY T2 
    NULL
 ref category_id,created_at,user_id,catcrbabusr catcrbabusr 4 admin_bt.T1.category_id 1148 3.33 Using where; Using index

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I exactly understand the logic of your query, but the following query does at least produce the same result (and surely in significantly less time):

This assumes an index on (user_id, category_id,created_at)

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM notes x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , category_id
            , MAX(created_at) created_at
         FROM notes
        WHERE user_id IN(2)
        GROUP
           BY user_id
            , category_id
     ) y
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id
   AND y.category_id = x.category_id
   AND y.created_at = x.created_at;
```

Here's another idea you might like to play with...

```
SELECT id
     , created_at
     , user_id
     , category_id
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = category_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev := category_id
         FROM notes x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars
        WHERE user_id = 2
        ORDER  
           BY category_id
            , created_at
      ) n
  WHERE i <= 2;
```

Comment: Can't see where I can set the number of rows per category. I assume it's because there is no such functionality which is important for me. May be I'm not explained that point well enough.
N in my query is the amount of rows per category should be presented in result. For N = 1 my query will produce the same result as yours, just much slower. You can set N = 2 in my sqlfiddle link and see that in response there is 2 rows with category_id = 6.
Your query still could be useful at N = 1 as the performance is exceeds any expectations. Thanks for the response.

Comment: So ultimately, you would just like a query that returns the top n most recent rows per category for a given user?

Comment: user_id is just an example. The scope is irrelevant as I can figure out how to set it in any query. category_id and created_at is important parts as I don't need just random N rows per category but only first or last based on created_at.

Comment: The second query is fast, working properly and even somewhat(haven't properly tested yet) solves the problem with more than N results per category with equal created_at values.
That's the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Correlated queries are naturally expensive, specially when walking a high number of first level rows. They are often not suitable for OLTPs. They are OK for batch processing.

If you need to show this response to an online page, then maybe you should cache the results in your application and refresh it periodically (every 10 minutes?).

In any case, even with indexes, chances are this query will become more an more slow the bigger the table grows.

Another option is to pre-process the subquery periodically and store it in a table. Then query against it. This query will be suitable for quick reponses. I don't know if MySQL has it, but PostgreSQL has "materialized views" that serve just this purpose (that can be resfreshed on-demand).

Comment: (mysql doesn't presently)